# How to grant admin permission to AAD users in Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-server

Using portal.azure.com I've created SQL Server and SQL Database. I've set myself as the SQL Server admin.

I'm able to connect with my AAD account using SSMS.

I add another AAD users to my database:

```
use [MyDatabase]
CREATE USER [usename_emaildomain#EXT#@mydirectory.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

--add read permissions
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', [usename_emaildomain#EXT#@mydirectory.onmicrosoft.com]
```

But how do grant him admin rights so that he has full access to all databases? I'm able to sent only one admin in Azure Portal.

Comment: You need to put all users in a group and add that single group rather than a single user.

Comment: Ah, it's that simple. Do you want to write answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why SQL Azure only allows one security principal to be designated as admin but anyway....

You can assign one *user* or one *group*. So put all of your users in a group and assign that group as the administrator